# Automorphisms of matrix rings - part 2

Tags: matrices, group-theory, ring-theory

I am looking at automorphisms of matrix rings over arbitrary fields: $M_n(K)$.

Thanks to help from here, I now know that all of these automorphisms are inner and hence of the form:

$\rho : M \rightarrow PMP^{-1}$ where $P$ is an invertible matrix.

So, I have an epimorphism from $GL_n(K)$ to the automorphisms of my matrix ring.

It is clearly not an isomorphism as multiplying $P$ by a scalar will lead to the same automorphism.  So, I could restrict my attention to $SL_n(K)$ but it is still not necessarily an isomorphism.

Suppose $P$ and $Q$ generate the same automorphism then:

$$\forall M \in M_n(K): PMP^{-1} = QMQ^{-1}$$

$$P^{-1}PMP^{-1}Q = P^{-1}QMQ^{-1}Q$$

$$MP^{-1}Q = P^{-1}QM$$

So $P^{-1}Q$ must be in the centre of $M_n(K)$.

Hence my automorphism group appears to be isomorphic to the quotient of $GL_n(K)$ with its centre.  Alternatively, $SL_n(K)$ with its centre.

The quotient of $GL_n(K)$ with its centre is isomorphic to the group of inner automorphisms of $GL_n(K)$ so the group of automorphisms of $M_n(K)$ is isomorphic to the group of inner automorphisms of $GL_n(K)$.

A few questions:

1. Any mistakes above?
2. Is there any common name for this group?
3. Is this the end of the story for my classification of these automorphisms?

Comment: This is correct (except you used introduced the variable $M$ and then used $A$). Do you know the center of $GL_n(K)$?
By the way, for *any* group $G$, its group of inner automorphism is isomorphic to $G / Z(G)$, and this can be proven just like you did.

Comment: @nombre Thanks.  I have corrected the $M$ / $A$ mistake.  I was using $A$ in my paper notes but most replies to my previous question used $M$ so I tried to switch but did not do so fully.

Comment: @nombre Yes, the next step is to learn more about the centre of $GL_n(K)$.  I just (re)learned that for any group the group of inner automorphisms is isomorphic to $G/Z(G)$.  I say relearned since I am old and rusty, I might have known that decades ago.

Comment: Well, great! Once you find out what the center is, you'll have the answer to your second question. As for the classification, the automorphism group of the inner automorphism group acts transitively on it so from an algebraic perspective one could say you are done. From a geometric perspective however, you could still study the orbits of $(P,A) \mapsto PMP^{-1}$, and the eventual description of a corresponding invariant; this leads to a richer theory of similarity of matrices over a field.

Comment: @nombre Thanks again.  The suggestion of studying orbits and looking for invariants is interesting.  
I am have no particular target that I am aiming for.  This is not homework but an old man doing self-imposed brain exercises.

Comment: @nombre Ah, the centre of $GL_n(K)$ is just the non-zero scalar matrices and hence isomorphic to the multiplicative group of $K$.  For a moment, I had thought that it was a bit larger than that.  So, the exact nature of my quotient group will depend on the field and what roots of unity it has so quite different for $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ let alone more exotic fields.

Comment: Yes,this group is usually denoted $PGL_n(K)$ or $PGL(K^n)$ and called the projective linear group. As for the study of invariants, it is not easy to do it "alone", and perhaps a more interesting first step is the study of the Steinitz action of $GL_n(K)^2$ on $M_n(K)$ given by $(P,Q),M \mapsto PMQ^{-1}$.

Comment: @nombre Thanks yet again.  The projective linear group is ringing a very little bell.

Comment: @nombre While tidying up, I noticed that I had not accepted an answer for this question.  The reason is that it has no answer.  If you converted your comments to an answer, I would accept it.